# How to write Bash script to install and configure Postfix on Debian-based distros

Tags: bash, debian, postfix-mta, apt, debconf

How do I write a Bash script to install and configure Postfix (for Debian or Ubuntu).

This is how I install Postfix:

```
 sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Then I re-configure it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

How do I make a script which automatically answers the questions of the reconfiguration with a predefined set of answers? Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: how to write for backend (without prompting us)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To **show** the package related debconf keys and values use `debconf-show packagename`.

For example the package "samba-common":

To **get** a single key and value from commandline use `echo "get samba-common/encrypt_passwords" | debconf-communicate`.

To **set** a single key and value from commandline use `echo "set samba-common/encrypt_passwords false" | debconf-communicate`.

This has the advantage, that your changes will survive debian package upgrades.

All other configuration should done with teh adviced `postconf` utility.

Source: http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/2010/10/manipulating-debconf-settings-on.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. In more condensed terms, preseed debconf with your configuration values, then apt/dpkg will use the supplied values when installing, instead of asking you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the `postconf` tool instead of dpkg-reconfigure.